# Prove that, for any (possibly correlated) collection of random variables, $Var(\Sigma_{i=1}^{k} X_i) \leq k \Sigma _{i=1}^{k} Var(X_i)$.

Tags: statistics

Prove that, for any (possibly correlated) collection of random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3,...X_k$, $Var(\Sigma_{i=1}^{k} X_i) \leq k \Sigma _{i=1}^{k} Var(X_i)$. And construct an example with $k \geq 2$ where the equality holds.

I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You are getting down-voted because you did not say where the problem comes from or what you tried. We need such information to answer at the appropriate level. Maybe you can try it for $k = 2$ and edit that attempt into your question: $Var(X + Y) \leq 2(Var(X) + Var(Y)).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume w.l.o.g. $E[X_i] = 0$ and use the convexity of the function $x \mapsto x^2$:
$$\left(\frac{1}{n}x_1 + \ldots + \frac{1}{n} x_n\right)^2 \le \frac{1}{n}x_1^2 + \ldots + \frac{1}{n} x_n^2$$